# Disable positive button in alert dialog in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, alert

I am trying to disable okButton till the edit text is empty.I couldn't find a solution to it. I tried adding text watcher but I don't know how to disable positive button in that.

```
   val inputTxt = EditText(this)
        alert("Enter your mobile number") {
            customView = inputTxt
            inputTxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)
            inputTxt.setFilters(arrayOf<InputFilter>(InputFilter.LengthFilter(10)))
            inputTxt.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
            okButton {
                    startActivity(intentFor<NewActivity>()
            }

            
            isCancelable = false
            cancelButton { finish() }
        }.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible (in a clean way) with the `AlertDialog` API itself, but you could have your own "OK" button in the custom view that you've added. The main risk is that it is not garanteed to look exactly (same margins and paddings) as the regular "OK" button.